# logic and application to a combinatorics question (Two chess players)

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, elementary-set-theory

I have a logic question regarding the approach of a combinatorics problem:

"Two chess players,  and , are going to play 7 games. Each game has three possible outcomes: a win for  (which is a loss for ), a draw (tie), and a loss for  (which is a win for ). A win is worth 1 point, a draw is worth 0.5 points, and a loss is worth 0 points.

Assume that they are playing a best-of-7 match, where the match will end when either player has 4 points or when 7 games have been played, whichever is first. For example, if after 6 games the score is 4 to 2 in favor of , then  wins the match and they don’t play a 7th game. How many possible outcomes for the individual games are there, such that the match lasts for 7 games and  wins by a score of 4 to 3?"

This question has being asked and answered here [original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1285582/two-chess-players-a-and-b-are-going-to-play-7-games-there-are-three-possible)

Since the original answer is rather long, hence, I am using only part of the answer:
Player $A$ wins 3 games, draws 1 game and loses 2 games gives $\binom{6}{3} \binom{3}{1} \binom{2}{2}$; for my question.

The logic from the posted answer is that player $A$ plans out his game 3 wins, 1 draw, 2 loses and winning the last game, hence, $n$ is adjusted after a grouped outcome. However, in real life situation shouldn't it be $\binom{7}{1} \binom{6}{1} \cdots \binom{1}{1}$ where the outcome is adjusted after every game and player $A$ is only able to do $n-1$ "choose" 1 till the 7th game?

For clarity $n$ is from $\binom{n}{k}$, and my question is not about questioning the correctness of the answer from the original post but the approach and logic in live settings.

Kindly advise

Added info for clarity;
Sorry for the lack of vocabulary, there are probably better words/phases than my choice of "sequential choices". I'll try to express it in my best effort.

$\require{cancel}$
There are 7 games of which the players are to play in sequence, one game after another till the game ends at the 7th game. Therefore, shouldn't it be$\cancel {\binom{7}{1} \binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1}}$ when the choices are not determined until the current game ends. The logic  from Joffan and user2661923 answers makes sense to me where the 7 games are played simultaneously.

**Added info after seeing @user2661923's Addendum**:
Thanks to user2661923's Addendum, I realized that my alternate view of updating after each game should be using win,lose, and tie(WLT) instead(my original intuition = "strike-thru"). And is very tedious and risk over and under count.

Comment: In the linked problem, Joffan selected the positions of the wins, ties, and losses among the first six games.  That determines the sequence of events.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig My answer is supposed to also critique the OP's (i.e. original poster's) thinking.  I am having trouble doing that because I don't understand the OP's thought processes.  Are you able to understand his thinking?  If so, could you leave me a comment, explaining your take on his thinking, so that I can react to it?  Alternatively, could you post a separate answer where you dissect the OP's thinking?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig and to the OP: Okay, I think I see where the OP is headed now.  It will take me a few minutes.  I will add an Addendum, where I react to your approach, and then leave a comment, when done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just added an Addendum to my answer, to explore the analytical approach suggested by the original poster.

---

> How many possible outcomes for the individual games are there, such that the match lasts for 7 games and  wins by a score of 4 to 3?"

> The logic from the posted answer is that player $A$ plans out his game 3 wins, 1 draw, 2 loses and winning the last game, hence, $n$ is adjusted after a grouped outcome. However, in real life situation shouldn't it be $\binom{7}{1} \binom{6}{1} \cdots \binom{1}{1}$ where the outcome is adjusted after every game and player $A$ is only able to do $n-1$ "choose" 1 till the 7th game?

With respect to the paragraph immediately above, I do not understand what you are trying to say.  If you could edit your posting to re-word your analysis, then I can take a crack at examining your approach.

I had trouble following both the OP's analysis and the analysis of the linked question.  So, I will answer the question *from scratch*.

I am assuming that the outcome of (for example) A winning Game-1 and drawing Game-2 is considered distinct from A drawing Game-1 and winning Game-2.

---

Since the match went $7$ games, there are $2$ mutually exclusive cases, that will be explored separately:

- A Tied Game-7.  
  The variable $R$ will be used for enumeration here.
- A Won Game-7. 
  The variable $S$ will be used for enumeration here.

$\underline{\text{Case 1: A tied Game-7}}$
This implies that after $6$ games, A had scored (3 + 1/2) points.  This implies that during the first $6$ games, A won $k$ games, where $k$ is some element in $\{1,2,3\}.$

So, there will be $3$ subcases, based on how many of the 1st $6$ games that A won.  I will use the variables $R_1, R_2,$ and $R_3$ to represent the respective (mutually exclusive) enumerations, re $1,2,$ or $3$ wins.

$R_1 = \binom{6}{1} \times \binom{5}{5} = 6.$ 
The 1st factor identifies the game won, and the 2nd factor identifies the games tied.

$R_2 = \binom{6}{2} \times \binom{4}{3} = 60.$

$R_3 = \binom{6}{3} \times \binom{3}{1} = 60.$

$$R = R_1 + R_2 + R_3 = 126.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 2: A won Game-7}}$
This implies that the score was tied after Game-6. 
This implies that A tied an even number of the 1st $6$ games.

This implies that during the first $6$ games, A tied $k$ games, where $k$ is some element in $\{0,2,4,6\}.$

So, there will be $4$ subcases, based on how many of the 1st $6$ games that A tied.  I will use the variables $S_0, S_2, S_4,$ and $S_6$ to represent the respective (mutually exclusive) enumerations, re $0,2,4,$ or $6$ ties.

$S_0 = \binom{6}{0} \times \binom{6}{3} = 20.$ 
The 2nd factor refers to the number of games that A won.

$S_2 = \binom{6}{2} \times \binom{4}{2} = 90.$

$S_4 = \binom{6}{4} \times \binom{2}{1} = 30.$

$S_6 = \binom{6}{6} \times \binom{0}{0} = 1.$

$$S = S_0 + S_2 + S_4 + S_6 = 141.$$

---

Final computation:

$$R + S = 126 + 141 = 267.$$

---

**Addendum**
If I understand the OP's (i.e. original poster's) alternative approach, he wants to examine the outcomes of each game sequentially.  Then, after each game, he wants to create pertinent branches that reflect the plausible results of the games just played.  Then, he wants to compute an overall enumeration, based on this approach.

Although this approach is extremely clumsy (i.e. cumbersome), it is possible, as long as you are extremely careful.

The overall constraint is that player A won 4-3, with the match lasting 7 games.

I will map out satisfying sequences, so that a sequence like WTL... refers to player A winning Game-1, tieing Game-2, and losing Game-3.  Then, the overall enumeration will be the number of satisfying sequences.

There are $3$ choices for how the sequence begins:

- W
- T
- L

Moving into Game-2, you again have the same $3$ choices, so now you have $9$ branches.

Moving into Game-3, you again have the same $3$ choices, so now you have $27$ branches.

These branches may be listed as:

WWW, WWT, WWL 
WTW, WTT, WTL 
WLW, WLT, WLL

TWW, TWT, TWL 
TTW, TTT, TTL 
TLW, TLT, TLL

LWW, LWT, LWL 
LTW, LTT, LTL 
LLW, LLT, LLL

---

Now, each of the $27$ possible outcomes of the first $3$ games, as shown above, will be individually explored.  For each such outcome, the possible sequences through game 6 will be listed and counted.  There is no need to take the sequence beyond game 6, since the sequence through game 6 uniquely determines the game 7 outcome.

Note that for the sequence to go $7$ games, with player A the winner, the number of points accumulated by player A after $6$ games must be either $3$ or $3.5$.

I will use the variable $O_k$ to represent the number of sequences based on the first $3$ games having outcome $k$ above, where $k \in \{1,2,3,\cdots, 27\}.$

$O_1:~$ WWW 
WWWTLL, WWWLTL, WWWLLT, WWWLLL 
$O_1 = 4.$

$O_2:~$ WWT 
WWTwLL, WWTLWL, WWTLLW 
WWTTTL, WWTTLT, WWTLTT 
WWTTLL, WWTLTL, WWTLLT 
$O_2 = 9.$

$O_3:~$ WWL 
WWLWTL, WWLWLT, WWLTWL, WWWTLW, WWWLWT, WWWLTW 
WWLTTT 
WWWWLL, WWWLWL, WWWLLW, 
WWWTTL, WWWTLT, WWWLTT 
$O_3 = 13.$

$O_4:~$ WTW 
$O_4$ represents having exactly (2.5) points after $3$ games.  Therefore, since this is the same as $O_2$, the $9$ Game-4 through Game-6 continuations that were listed for $O_2$ must exactly match the satisfying Game-4 through Game-6 continuations for $O_4$. 
I will refer to this type of shortcut as 
$O_4 = O_2 = 9.$

$O_5:~$ WTT 
$O_5$ represents having $2$ points after Game-3, which matches the number of points, after Game-3, for $O_3$. 
Therefore, 
$O_5 = O_3 = 13.$

$O_6:~$ WTL 
WTLWWL, WTLWLW, WTLLWW, WTLWTT, WTLTWT, WTLTTW 
WTLWTL, WTLWLT, WTLTWL, WTLTLW, WTLLWT, WTLLTW 
WTLTTT 
$O_6 = 13.$

$O_7:~$ WLW 
$O_7 = O_3 = 13.$

$O_8:~$ WLT 
$O_8 = O_6 = 13.$

$O_9:~$ WLL 
WLLWWT, WLLWTW, WLLTWW 
WLLWWL, WLLWLW, WLLLWW 
WLLWTT, WLLTWT, WLLTTW 
$O_9 = 9.$

Running total of: 
$O_1 + O_2 + \cdots + O_9$ 
$= 4 + 9 + 13 + 9 + 13 + 13 + 13 + 13 + 9 = 96.$

---

$O_{10}:~$ TWW 
$O_{10} = O_2 = 9.$

$O_{11}:~$ TWT 
$O_{11} = O_3 = 13.$

$O_{12}:~$ TWL 
$O_{12} = O_6 = 13.$

$O_{13}:~$ TTW 
$O_{13} = O_3 = 13.$

$O_{14}:~$ TTT 
$O_{14} = O_6 = 13.$

$O_{15}:~$ TTL 
$O_{15} = O_9 = 9.$

$O_{16}:~$ TLW 
$O_{16} = O_6 = 13.$

$O_{17}:~$ TLT 
$O_{17} = O_9 = 9.$

$O_{18}:~$ TLL 
TLLWWW, TLLWWT, TLLWTW, TLLTWW 
$O_{18} = 4.$

Running total of: 
$O_{10} + O_{11} + \cdots + O_{18}$ 
$= 9 + 13 + 13 + 13 + 13 + 9 + 13 + 9 + 4 = 96.$

Running total of: 
$O_{1} + \cdots + O_{18}$ 
$= 96 + 96 = 192.$

---

$O_{19}:~$ LWW 
$O_{19} = O_3 = 13.$

$O_{20}:~$ LWT 
$O_{20} = O_6 = 13.$

$O_{21}:~$ LWL 
$O_{21} = O_9 = 9.$

$O_{22}:~$ LTW 
$O_{22} = O_6 = 13.$

$O_{23}:~$ LTT 
$O_{23} = O_9 = 9.$

$O_{24}:~$ LTL 
$O_{24} = O_{18} = 4.$

$O_{25}:~$ LLW 
$O_{25} = O_9 = 9.$

$O_{26}:~$ LLT 
$O_{26} = O_{18} = 4.$

$O_{27}:~$ LLL 
LLLWWW 
$O_{27} = 1.$

Running total of: 
$O_{19} + O_{20} + \cdots + O_{27}$ 
$= 13 + 13 + 9 + 13 + 9 + 4 + 9 + 4 + 1 = 75.$

Final total of: 
$O_{1} + \cdots + O_{27}$ 
$= 192 + 75 = 267.$

Comment: thank you for the reply. As mentioned, I am asking in regards to the logic in "live" setting.  From your example $ S_2 = \binom{6}{2}  \binom{4}{2}$, those are player $A$'s predetermined choices rather than the sequential $n-1$ choices. fyi, your corrected answer of adding $S_0$ corresponds to the answer from the original post by Joffan. And as mentioned, I'm not questioning whether the answers are correct but rather; whether predetermined choices or choices in sequence is appropriate in this situation.

Comment: @ManOnTheMoon I don't understand what you intend by the phrase **sequential n-1 choices**.  This is why I could not comment on it.  I will be happy to examine any alternative approach that you have.  However, first, you have to edit your posting to make your alternative approach, **much, much, clearer**.  I can not react to your alternative analysis until I understand your thought processes.  I have never seen any analysis on any problem of this nature that involved *sequential choices*.  You will need to make your thinking crystal clear.

Comment: @ManOnTheMoon  While this solution is phrased differently from Joffan's solution, both Joffan and user2661923 selected the positions of the wins, ties, and losses in the first six games.  That determines the sequence of events.

Comment: @user2661923, thank you for helping me understand the approach, I've added more information in my question. Hope it  gives more clarity on what i am trying to express.

Comment: What the OP is saying is that the outcome of the first match limits the number of possible sequences for the remaining matches, that the outcome of the first two matches limits the number of possible sequences for the remaining matches, and so forth.  Of course, you counted all those possibilities in your calculations, without those case dependencies.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig, i understand both are essentially the same and are to my understanding correct when the 7 games are simultaneously played.

Comment: @ManOnTheMoon Please wait for my Addendum.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig, spot on! That is what i meant. Thank you for making it more logical with your wordings.

Comment: @ManOnTheMoon See the just added Addendum to my answer.

Comment: @user2661923 I'm sorry that i probably still wasn't too clear, hence, misled you into thinking that I was approaching it in terms of reflecting "the plausible results of the games just played." I've added more info, hopeful it is clearer now. However, kindly keep the Addendum as is because it is intriguing to see how you approached it and i still need time to process it. Thank you

Comment: @ManOnTheMoon Then, what type of analysis are you looking for.  I can add an Addendum-2 to my answer.  But first, I have to have a very clear understanding of what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm actually analyzing how player $A$ will calculate the number of outcomes as he is playing each game. During game 1 he is free to choose from win,lose,tie as long as the set consists of at least 1 of each win,lose,tie. His choices between win,lose,tie shrinks because of the points and 7 games requirements.

Comment: @ManOnTheMoon Yes, but they do not shrink consistently.  That is why, if you look at the $27$ cases in the Addendum, with each case identifying how many ways there are of continuing the sequence through games $4$ through $6$, that the number of ways of extending the sequence potentially varies from case to case.  This means that your approach seems to require manual counting, which is what I did in the Addendum.  This also explains why your approach is never used, as a general attack on such problems.

Comment: @user2661923, after rereading all the comments and your addendum I am finally able to realized my missing puzzle. And i agree that my approach is too tedious with risk of overcount. I deleted my added info to avoid confusing other users if they stumble upon this post. Thank you again.